# error while installing gnome in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gnome, 14.04

i have tried installing gnome from repositories i.e. from ubuntu software centre but it shows this error while installing

[image]
currently i am having AMD graphic card gallium 0.4 on AMD rs780 so can it support gnome complexities

Comment: ok i will add it in my edited question

Comment: is this enough for my question

Comment: ok i will get it done

Comment: is this ok for you now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with the graphics card. Follow the steps below to see if it works this time. First, let’s add the GNOME 3 PPA to Ubuntu’s Software Sources. This can be done using a GUI but it is far easier to achieve using the command line.

Open a new Terminal window and enter the following command, entering your user password when asked:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

With the PPA added and our package list updated we can move on to installing GNOME 3.10 itself. To do this run the following command, again entering your user password when prompted:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

It can take a while for all the necessary packages and components to be fetched and installed, so try to be patient.

Midway through the installation a prompt will appear in the Terminal asking you to choose what display manager – aka “login screen” – should be used by default.

This decision is entirely up to you; both Ubuntu’s Unity Greeter and the GNOME Display Manager let you easily switch between desktop sessions (handy if you want to keep Unity or another desktop around) but only GDM offers GNOME-specific features such as lock-screen notifications.

When you’re ready to decide make your selection using the up/down arrow keys and hit ‘Enter/Return’ to confirm. The installation will then proceed.

If it does not work, run `sudo apt-get -f install`, then try the above commands again.

In case it does not work, install Ubuntu GNOME instead of Ubuntu. It is actually Ubuntu itself but with GNOME instead of Unity. It is also officially supported by Canonical. Note that this will erase all data from your existing Ubuntu installation. The link to download is below.

[Get Ubuntu GNOME](http://ubuntugnome.org/download/)

Comment: it does'nt work

Comment: is gnome better than unity if yes in which aspects is it better than unity

Comment: It entirely depends on you which interface do you most like. I prefer unity for ubuntu, and gnome looks good on my fedora installation. Which one do you most like.